# Automatic counter show unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout

I have two pieces of codes, as shown bellow.

The first is a clock that shows the current time, updated every second. It works perfectly!

The second one is a very similar code, but instead of showing the current time, it is a counter that increments itself every second.

This is where we can see an unexpected behavior because it is okay for the first few seconds, but from the second 4 or 5 (actually it may happen since the first second, but visible from the forth, fifth second) it starts to shows all the previous values (seconds) quite quickly...  and when we reach about 10 sec, it is not even possible to see the values.

Note that if I rid of the "setInterval" function, and manually increment the values clicking the button, it works as expected (we see only the incremented value on the screen).

What may be happening? I am new to react and I appreciate any help ;)

Code 1:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
    let time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    let [now, changeTime] = useState(time);

    function getCurrentTime() {
       
        let innerTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
        changeTime(innerTime);
    }

    setInterval(getCurrentTime, 1000);


    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>{now}</h1>
            <button onClick={getCurrentTime}>Get Time</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Code 2:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
    let time = 0;
    let [now, changeTime] = useState(0);

    function getCurrentTime() {
       
        let innerTime = now;
        changeTime(innerTime+1);
    }

    setInterval(getCurrentTime, 1000);


    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>{now}</h1>
            <button onClick={getCurrentTime}>Get Time</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

The index.js is a quite straightforward as show bellow:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";


const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Comment: Could you provide some snippet of these react components?

Comment: Well for a start, `window.clearTimeout(innerTime)`, you're not clearing the timeout, you're passing a Date object.

Comment: A new interval is created each render cycle. Intervals need only be instantiated once when component mounts. (don't forgot to clear the interval when unmounting!)

Comment: You should be using clearInterval with an interval, not clearTimeout. And you should be declaring the setInterval variable above the function definition that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** By not conditionally setting an interval it is instantiated each render cycle and the previous interval isn't being cleared.

```
function App() {
    let time = 0;
    let [now, changeTime] = useState(0);

    function getCurrentTime() {

        let innerTime = now;
        changeTime(innerTime+1);
    }

    setInterval(getCurrentTime, 1000); // <-- Creates a new interval each render cycle!


    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>{now}</h1>
            <button onClick={getCurrentTime}>Get Time</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**One Possible Solution:** If you are simply wanting an auto-counter then something as simple as the state and an effect to setup/cleanup the timer is all that is necessary:

```
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Use functional state update since next state depends on previous
    const timerID = setInterval(() => setCount(c => c + 1), 1000);
    // return interval cleanup function
    return () => clearInterval(timerID);
  }, []) // Empty dependency array to invoke effect once when component mounted

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>{count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit dry-leaf-f4in8]